# Unity C# Delegate: Listener receives null arguments when invoking it with non null arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, delegates, game-development

I found out a weird behavior on Unity's C# delegates that I can't understand.

Using:

- Unity 2020.3.33f
- .NET 4.x

---

**Context**

I am coding a script(*FirebaseAuthManager.cs*) to handle login through Firebase Auth.

I created a delegate that gets invoked every time a sign-in status change happens. The plan is to allow other scripts to listen to sign-in events.

The code of *FirebaseAuthManager.cs* looks like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase.Auth;
using System;

public class FirebaseAuthManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Firebase Auth Manager custom types
    public enum AuthStateChangedEvent { SIGN_IN, SIGN_OUT }
    public delegate void OnAuthStateChanged(AuthStateChangedEvent stateChangedEvent, FirebaseUser user);
    public delegate void OnSignInError(string errorMessage);


    // Firebase Auth class variables
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseUser user;

    // FurebaseAuthManager event delegates
    private OnAuthStateChanged onAuthStateChanged;
    private OnSignInError onSignInError;

    [Header("Debug")]

    [SerializeField] private string uid;
    [SerializeField] private bool signedIn;



    #region initialization

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitializeFirebase();

        // login for debug propouses.
        LoginUser("testmail@mail.com", "12341234");



    }

    private void Start()
    {

        //Logout();
    }

    private void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        auth.StateChanged += AuthStateChanged;
        //AuthStateChanged(this, null);
    }

    #endregion



    #region Firebase events listeners

    private void AuthStateChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (auth.CurrentUser != this.user)
        {
            bool signedIn = this.user != auth.CurrentUser && auth.CurrentUser != null;

            if (!signedIn && this.user != null)
            {
                Debug.Log("Signed out " + user.UserId);
                this.user = null;
                onAuthStateChanged?.Invoke(AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_OUT, this.user);
                
                // Just to show on inspector
                this.signedIn = false;
                this.uid = "NA";
            }
            else if (signedIn)
            {
                user = auth.CurrentUser;
                Debug.Log("Signed in " + this.user.UserId);
                onAuthStateChanged?.Invoke(AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_IN, this.user);

                // Just to show on inspector
                this.signedIn = true;
                this.uid = this.user.UserId;
            }
        }
    }


    #endregion


    #region FirebaseAuthManager's Event subscription 

    public void AddOnAuthStateChanged(OnAuthStateChanged listener)
    {
        if (listener == null) return;

        if (this.user != null)    
        {
            listener?.Invoke(AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_IN, this.user);
        }

        this.onAuthStateChanged += listener;
    }


    public void RemoveOnAuthStateChanged(OnAuthStateChanged listener)
    {
        if (listener == null) return;

        this.onAuthStateChanged -= listener;
    }


    public void AddOnAuthStateChanged(OnSignInError listener)
    {


        this.onSignInError += listener;
    }


    public void RemoveOnAuthStateChanged(OnSignInError listener)
    {
        if (listener == null) return;

        this.onSignInError -= listener;
    }

    #endregion


    #region Operation methods

    public void CreateUser(string email, string password)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
        auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                //OnUserCreationCancelled();
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception);


                return;
            }

            // Firebase user has been created.
            FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;

            Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
                newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        });

    }

    public void LoginUser(string email, string password)
    {

        auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled: " + task.Exception.Message);
                InvokeOnSignInErrorEvent(task.Exception);

                return;
            }
            else if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync encountered an error: " + task.Exception.Message);
                InvokeOnSignInErrorEvent(task.Exception.InnerException.InnerException);

                return;
            }
    



            Debug.Log("Mensaje Login: " + task.Exception.Message);

            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("User signed in successfully: {0} ({1})",
                newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
            user = newUser;
        });

    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        auth.SignOut();
    }

    public bool IsLoggedIn()
    {
        if (user == null || user.IsAnonymous)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (user == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region FirebaseAuthManager's Event Triggers

    private void InvokeOnSignInErrorEvent(Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.Log("ERROR AUTH: " + GetErrorMessage(exception));
        string errorMessage = GetErrorMessage(exception);
        onSignInError?.Invoke(errorMessage);
    }

    private static string GetErrorMessage(Exception exception)
    {
        Debug.Log(exception.ToString());
        Firebase.FirebaseException firebaseEx = exception as Firebase.FirebaseException;
        if (firebaseEx != null)
        {
            var errorCode = (AuthError)firebaseEx.ErrorCode;
            return GetErrorMessage(errorCode);
        }

        return exception.ToString();
    }

    private static string GetErrorMessage(AuthError errorCode)
    {
        var message = "";
        switch (errorCode)
        {
            case AuthError.AccountExistsWithDifferentCredentials:
                message = "Ya existe la cuenta con credenciales diferentes";
                break;
            case AuthError.MissingPassword:
                message = "Se requiere una contraseña";
                break;
            case AuthError.WeakPassword:
                message = "La contraseña es debil";
                break;
            case AuthError.WrongPassword:
                message = "El usuario no existe o la contraseña es incorrecta";
                break;
            case AuthError.EmailAlreadyInUse:
                message = "Ya existe la cuenta con este correo electrónico";
                break;
            case AuthError.InvalidEmail:
                message = "El email no es válido";
                break;
            case AuthError.MissingEmail:
                message = "Se requiere un email";
                break;
            case AuthError.Failure:
                message = "Se ha produciido un error";
                break;
            case AuthError.InvalidCredential:
                message = "Las credenciales no son válidas";
                break;
            case AuthError.UserDisabled:
                message = "El usuario está deshabilitado";
                break;
            case AuthError.OperationNotAllowed:
                message = "Operación no permitida";
                break;
            case AuthError.CredentialAlreadyInUse:
                message = "Las credenciales están en uso";
                break;
            case AuthError.TooManyRequests:
                message = "Has realizado demasiados intentos";
                break;
            case AuthError.UserNotFound:
                message = "El usuario no existe o la contraseña es incorrecta";
                break;
            case AuthError.AppNotAuthorized:
                message = "La aplicación no está autorizada";
                break;
            case AuthError.SessionExpired:
                message = "La sesion ha expirado";
                break;
            case AuthError.AppNotVerified:
                message = "App no verificada";
                break;
            case AuthError.AppVerificationFailed:
                message = "La verificacion de la app ha fallado";
                break;
            case AuthError.CaptchaCheckFailed:
                message = "El captcha es incorrecto";
                break;
            case AuthError.InvalidAppCredential:
                message = "Las credenciales de la app no son válidas";
                break;
            case AuthError.MissingAppCredential:
                message = "Faltan las credenciales de la app";
                break;
            case AuthError.InvalidClientId:
                message = "La id del cliente no es válida";
                break;

            default:
                message = "Error";
                break;
        }
        return message;
    }
    #endregion


}
```

I have a second script that only should work when a user is logged in. The relevant fragment of code looks like this:

```
 FirebaseAuthManager authManager;

        #region initialization

        private void Start()
        {
            authManager = FindObjectOfType<FirebaseAuthManager>();
            authManager.AddOnAuthStateChanged(OnAuthStateChange);

        }

        private void OnAuthStateChange(FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent eventType, FirebaseUser user)
        {
            switch (eventType)
            {
                case FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_IN:
                    StartTable(user);
                    break;


                case FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_OUT:
                    StopTable();
                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }



        #endregion
```

---

**The problem**

As you can see, if an object subscribes to *FirebaseAuthManager*'s "AuthStateChangeEvent" event through the method:

```
public void AddOnAuthStateChanged(OnAuthStateChanged listener)
    {
        if (listener == null) return;

        if (this.user != null)    
        {
            listener?.Invoke(AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_IN, this.user);
        }

        this.onAuthStateChanged += listener;
    }
```

The listener will be called in case there is already a user signed in.

Also is impossible to call it with null values.

So what a surprise when I found out on debugger that, even if the line

```
listener?.Invoke(AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_IN, this.user);
```

was executed with both arguments fine and "not null", then the event listener (in the second script)

```
 private void OnAuthStateChange(FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent eventType, FirebaseUser user)
        {
            switch (eventType)
            {
                case FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_IN:
                    StartTable(user);
                    break;


                case FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_OUT:
                    StopTable();
                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

received the event the argument *Firebase user* as null.

How can this be possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there was some kind of odd bug.

After commenting the method

```
private void OnAuthStateChange(FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent eventType, FirebaseUser user)
        {
            switch (eventType)
            {
                case FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_IN:
                    StartTable(user);
                    break;


                case FirebaseAuthManager.AuthStateChangedEvent.SIGN_OUT:
                    StopTable();
                    break;


                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

running a test using lambda and restoring the original code started working as expected.

No idea what could be going on, but seems fixed now.